# Pros and cons of position as properties of a spatial object?

Tags: simulation, 3d

Building games and simulation frameworks, it seems I am regularly hounded by this conundrum:

Let's say you have a 2D grid, and you have an crate in that grid. I can put the coordinates on the crate, or somewhere else.

```
# Option A:
grid = Grid()
crate = Crate()
grid.add(x,y,crate)

# Option B:
grid = Grid()
crate = Crate(x,y)
grid.add(crate)
```

I prefer option A because why should the crate know where it is? Its position only makes sense in the context of its holding space (the grid). *However*, it seems that everywhere I encounter spatial positioning, Option B is used. I have noticed that this somehow does make the code simpler, and indeed more intuitive. However it irks my sense of conceptual integrity.

There is another option which seems to me to be an additional level of complexity, so I tend to avoid it:

```
# Option C
grid = Grid()
index = GridIndex(grid)
crate = Crate()
index.add(x,y,crate)
```

Some inconclusive thoughts:

Thought 1:
When trying to find items quickly, given a coordinate, we want option A, or C. With those we have some hope of indexing. Well with C, we have indexing explicitly of course.

Thought 2:
Option B suffers from this problem:

```
# Problem
grid = Grid()
crate = Crate(cx,cy)
room = Room(rx,ry)
grid.add(crate)
grid.add(room)
# oh actually crate is in the room
room.add(crate)
```

Now, the crate has coordinates intended for a grid, but it is actually in a room.

For me the above issues are fundamental conceptual issues that I cannot resolve. Have I missed why Option B is everywhere, and Option A is nowhere? What are the other pros and cons of A vs B vs C?

**Aside**
For me, it is useful to consider other similar(?) structures. The values of a dict/hash-table, do not typically know their own key. So, in this case, they use my conceptually preferred option, Option A.

Comment: Whoever down voted, any chance of some constructive criticism?

Comment: Entity Component System ticks all the boxes. The alternative is to use a Connector pattern. When you add the object to the grid, it handshakes by offering the object a `connection` which in this case would contain/permit access to the location of the object in the grid. Of course the object does not have to care about receiving a connection.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that option B is used almost everywhere is that it enables very streamlined rendering operations. If you don't look at positions but at coordinate system transformations, it is apparent that each object needs a transformation relative to the coordinate system of its container so that it moves and rotates with its container. When rendering, each object is responsible for composing its transformation with the outer coordinate system to yield its local coordinate system, render itself and possibly its contained objects, and return to the outer coordinate system (which normally is done by popping from a coordinate system stack).

If you move objects between different containers, you need to adjust their transformation, of course, but this isn't really complicated if you use a 3d geometry library.

Finding objects given some point is usually accomplished by keeping a bounding volume (box or sphere) which encompasses the object and all of its contained objects. Grid lookup only works reasonably well in 2dimensonal spaces without rotations and scaling.

Of course 3d rendering engines limit the number of objects that need to be considered for rendering and other operations, for example by keeping a number of "rooms" or other bounded spaces and only considering objects within the currently visible rooms.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a fairly straightforward 2-dimensional simulation, I often prefer style 'A' and store the coordinates and possibly axis-aligned bounding box of the object directly into the spatial index or grid structure and nowhere else. Aside from satisfying the conceptual integrity you mentioned, it tends to eliminate redundancy since efficient spatial indices and grid implementations will tend to want to store the center position and half-size of the element anyway even if it's redundant to avoid cache misses having to dereference individual objects at random locations in memory to do things like coarse collision tests. It also tends to be more efficient to perform 2D rasterization while traversing the 2D grid or spatial index, since it can plot pixels in a more cache-friendly pattern by rendering elements in, say, a top-left to bottom-right order for the visible cells of the grid.

I think the streamlined rendering cited in the other example is a very likely reason why a lot of engines favor the B-style approach of having entities directly store their coordinates. To extend on that a bit, a lot of engines that perform simulations such as game engines often use a motion hierarchy involving motion parenting. For example, a robot hand should rotate along with its forearm when the robot elbow is bent, so the hand/wrist might be parented to the forearm (the hand wrist becomes a motion child of the parent). It might become a bit awkward if we have a sophisticated motion evaluation of this sort if the objects we are trying to render and evaluate don't directly store their motion data and instead, we had to go through the grid or spatial index.

Another possibility that popped in my head is parallelism. A grid or spatial index tends to be a fairly hefty structure to store and copy around and slightly expensive to traverse if all we want to do is copy element data into an array, e.g. So if we want to do things like render a frame in parallel simultaneously while the simulation is mutating the grid without the renderer having to wait, it's probably going to be so much cheaper if we simply `memcpy` the elements to render from one array to another than having to go through the grid or make a copy of the entire grid.

If you are really hardcore about this stuff though and hate bundling disparate data into a single object, I find the Entity Component System to be a wonderful fit for sufficiently complex projects. In those cases, you could create a dedicated position or motion component which stores the coordinates of entities in your simulation and separate that data away from, say, the data required for a cargo object, or sprites stored for rendering, which gives that clean separation along with making it easier to see what can be safely multithreaded, find significantly reduced coupling, and find it much easier to reason about where data is accessed and mutated in the codebase. It does come with a somewhat hefty upfront cost and a learning curve though, so I would only recommend it for sufficiently complex projects that really benefit from it.